# SlideShowExtender - How to get the current picture?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using asp control SlideShowExtender in a aspx page.

I am using the previous and next buttons.

I want to add a delete button. Is there a way to find out which picture the user is currently on? I'm having a hard time finding how to get the name of the image SlideShowExtender is currently showing.

Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$find("<%= slideshowextend1.ClientID %>")._currentValue.ImagePath;
$find("<%= slideshowextend1.ClientID %>")._currentValue.Name;
```

Comment: This is coming up with a empty string for me =(

Answer (score 0):

Crazy workaround

Add MouseDown event to image *(OnClick would not work)*

asp:Image runat="server" ID="MainImage" Width="1000" ImageUrl="" onmousedown="javascript:return MainClick();"

JavaScript

```
    function MainClick() {
        i = document.getElementById('<%=MainImage.ClientID %>');
        c = document.getElementById('<%=MainImageClick.ClientID %>');
        c.value = i.getAttribute("src");
        __doPostBack(null, null);
        return true;
    }

</script>
```

C# - there is probably some way of setting the sender but I am working on a over budget project

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (IsPostBack)

```
{
    string mainImageClick = MainImageClick.Value;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mainImageClick))
      DoMainImageClick(mainImageClick);
    MainImageClick.Value = string.Empty;
 }
```

}